# Memory Issue using OO (soffice) as batch conversion service

Tags: memory, conversion, openoffice, libreoffice

I have a Java Web Application that uses an OOo instance (on the same environment) started in headless mode as batch converter.

- environment is RHEL 5.5.
- The OpenOffice version is 3.1.

I've run some tests and I found that after about 1000 conversion the resident memory of the soffice process was around 99% of the total. 
OpenOffice finally crashed.

I would use this server as a batch converter for documents, but this memory issue is requiring a daily restart according to the medium amount of conversion request that we have.

I know that this memory issue is affecting OO since release 2.
I would know if there is a solution, or if using a Windows Server instead of Linux could solve the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in ["OpenOffice Server Daemon"](http://oodaemon.sourceforge.net/README.html).

By managing the conversion it enables you to:

- take advantages of multithreading during conversion by parallelizing them
- reduce the impact of memory leaks by restarting each soffice process in case of a crash and/or after a predefined number of conversions

A good point is you don't have to modify any of your code, the interface to the server is the same than the one to OO.

Comment: looks interesting. Do you know oooServer (see the edit in my answer for link) and if so, have any experience with it?

Comment: Sorry I don't, I found OO Server Daemon a few months ago while looking at the conversion tool in OO.o but didn't use it. Given the lack of commits you may want to try the solution you found (oooServer) first because it has been updated more recently.

Comment: my customer decided to have his own system of handling OOo instances implemented. More specialized to the task at hand, so I wont come around testing it :( I was looking forward to it. Maybe the other day.